# Interface Object Always Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, interface, nullreferenceexception

I created "personFuntionality" object from "PersonFuntionality" interface.
that Interface has a method to save details of a person.The Problem is personFuntionality always has a null value.

```
public PersonFuntionality personFuntionality;



 try
            {
                List<beans.Person> prsn = new List<beans.Person>();

                beans.Person psn = new beans.Person();

                psn.PersonId = Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text.Trim());
                psn.PersonName = txtName.Text.Trim();
                psn.PersonCity = txtCity.Text.Trim();

                prsn.Add(psn);

                //prsn.PersonId = Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text.Trim());
                //prsn.PersonName = txtName.Text.Trim();
                //prsn.PersonCity = txtCity.Text.Trim();

                if (personFuntionality != null)
                {
                    bool success = personFuntionality.SavePersonDetails(prsn);

                    if (success == true)
                    {
                        lblResult.Text = "success";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblResult.Text = "Failed";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lblResult.Text = "Object Null";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: You are simply defining the `personFuntionality` variable & not initializing, so by default it will be null right?

Comment: I can't see where you assign personFunctionality to an instance. Do you maybe want to assign it by calling the constructer?

Comment: personFuntionality is a variable created from "PersonFuntionality" **interface**

Comment: Please don't ever write code like `catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception(ex.Message); }`. It's just inviting bugs in your code.

Comment: thank you  Enigmativity..I'll keep that in my mind.I'm still a newbie.

Answer (score 5):

You never instantiated the `personFuntionality` object in give code but just declared it. You can instantiate it as under. I assume you have parameter less constructor for class `PersonFuntionalityImlementorClass` that implemented *PersonFuntionality* Interface.

```
public PersonFuntionality personFuntionality = new  PersonFuntionalityImlementorClass();
```

You have the interface reference personFuntionality. You have to assign a implementer class object to it.

[Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx)

> An interface contains only the signatures of methods, properties,
>   events or indexers. A class or struct that implements the interface
>   must implement the members of the interface that are specified in the
>   interface definition. In the following example, class
>   ImplementationClass must implement a method named SampleMethod that
>   has no parameters and returns void.

```
interface ISampleInterface
{
    void SampleMethod();
}

class ImplementationClass : ISampleInterface
{
    // Explicit interface member implementation:  
    void ISampleInterface.SampleMethod()
    {
        // Method implementation.
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // Declare an interface instance.
        ISampleInterface obj = new ImplementationClass();

        // Call the member.
        obj.SampleMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: As per OP, `PersonFuntionality` is an interface.

Comment: Thanks for pointing just missed that, he has to instantiate the implementor   class of Interface.

Comment: PersonFuntionality is an Interface so It's not possible to create an instance from it eh ?

Comment: @shutterrox, Interface could not be initiated directly but the concrete class that implements the interface could be instantiated.